# Way to add generated object probertys to autocomplete in IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

is there a way to add generated obj keys to the IDE's autocomplete ?

For example

```
for(file of modelFiles){
   const parsedFile = parseFile(file);
   db[parsedFile.name] = require(parsedFile.path)(sequelize, Sequelize);
}
```

One of the Models is "User" i would like to get db.User now in autocomplete
Best Regards and thanks for your time

Comment: What's your current used programming language in the code? You need to write an IDEA plugin to add something to the completion list based on your code.

Comment: Hello, JavaScript. so there is no easy way ?

Comment: Yes, there is no easy way here.